# Is there a way to encode unicode into a human readable variant of base64 (in python)

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, radix

I would like to encode user input values coming from a web interface in such a way that I can pass the data into my system in a safe way. In other words, I want to strip out what I consider bad characters such as quotes and brackets, etc.

I could use base64 and it would work fine. However, I'd like to be able to read the strings if they were originally alphanumeric in a human readable format at the lower layers.

So, `'Nice string'` would be encoded to `'Nice string'` but ``` 'N@sty!!``string!!))' ``` would be encoded to something like `"N=E2sty=B3=B3=XY=XYstring=B3=B3=B1=B1"`.
I just made that up but you get the idea.

Does such an encoding format exist and particularly does it exist in python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
urllib.quote("'N@sty!!`` string,!!))'",safe=" ,.").replace('%','=')
'=27N=40sty=21=21=60=60 string,=21=21=29=29=27'
```

Comment: couldn't you add a `" "` to the second parameter of urllib.quote to keep spaces?

Answer (score 0):

I think [Punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) would meet your needs.

```
import encodings.punycode
encoded = encodings.punycode.punycode_encode(inputstr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `urllib.quote`:

```
>>> urllib.quote("Nice String");
'Nice%20String'
>>> urllib.quote("N@sty!!``string!!))");
'N%40sty%21%21%60%60string%21%21%29%29'
```